# Camel Route - Spring DSL

Tags: apache-camel

looking forward for some pointers to improve the following camel route definition.

```
<route shutdownRunningTask="CompleteAllTasks" customId="true" id="ftpSend1">
    <from uri="file:e://cameltesting/in?noop=true" />
    <wireTap uri="seda:inputQueue">
        <setHeader headerName="fileName">
            <simple>${file:name.noext}-${date:now:yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS}-${file:size}.${file:ext}</simple>
        </setHeader>
    </wireTap>
    <to uri="file:e://cameltesting/out" />
</route>
<route shutdownRunningTask="CompleteAllTasks" customId="true" id="ftpSend2">
    <from uri="seda:inputQueue" />
    <to uri="spring-batch:backUpJob" />
</route>
```

1. FuceIDE installed in the eclipse is only considering the first part of the route in the design mode(camel editor). Is it an issue with IDE or are we missing out something in the route definition?
2. Can I use seda in production environment. we are expecting some large files through this route.
3. Is it possible to make the 2 routes as part a transaction?

Thanks in advance,

San

Comment: Actually, these are 3 questions...

Comment: 2.) You can use SEDA wherever you want, it is a stable component. It should be fine for large files since the processing will happen on a separate thread. 3.) Yes, look into transaction managers. After you configure one, just put <transacted/> at the beginning of your route

Comment: Look into the `disruptor` component, I've found it to be more performant than SEDA.